# Geeting metadata from TCP

Tags: .net, tcp

I am converting object to bytes array and sending this information from Client 1 to Client 2 through TCP(TCPListener) using c sharp. I want to tell client 2, for what purpose i have to use this information. How i can achieve this?

Is there a way I can send metadata as well with bytes?

Answer (score 2):

You are the sender and receiver of the TCP packet. You can design your own protocol on top of TCP which could be something such as.
First 3 bytes of the TCP message is the metadata for (1), (2) purposes.
Than you could parse the payload of the TCP message accordingly in the receiver side.

Comment: Can you please share any link where i can find similar implementation?

Answer (score 2):

TCP is just a byte stream; it has no concept of "metadata" vs "message", in fact it has no concept of "message" - any logical break between successive message is entirely down to you to encode. Because of that, there's usually a concept of "frames". For example, we could define a "frame" to be (where we're using the headers for metadata):

- 4 bytes, little-endian int32: {number of headers} (=H)
- 4 bytes, little-endian int32: {payload length in bytes} (=N)
- H ×

  - pure ASCII: {header-name}={header-value}\r\n
- payload: {N bytes}

but literally any scheme is available to us. In some cases, the metadata is simple and predictable, and you can essentially treat it as part of the message, with the *real* message as sub-data; for example, pretend that we're sending JSON; instead of sending:

```
{
    "somedata": 12345,
    // ...
}
```

we send:

```
{
    "blah-meatadata-whatever": "foo",
    "more-metadata": true,
    "content":
    {
        "somedata": 12345,
        // ...
    }
}
```